# How can I add a condition to my inline bash script to send an string using expect when that condition is met?

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh, logic

I'm using an inline script to connect to my servers, sometimes server is new and I have to type in a "YES" for the fingerprint to added, but most of my servers are old and I have connected to them many times, this is my inline script:

`expect -c 'spawn ssh MYHOST@MYSERVER; expect "Password:"; send "MY PASSWORD"; interact'`

How can I add a condition to also look for the string "FINGER PRINT" or "the authenticity of host" and if there is one of them, then send a "YES"?

Thank you everyone.

I tried to find examples of this but unfortunately I couldn't find an example that I can use to fix my problem.

Comment: `expect` isn't really the right tool for this (or rather, it's more general than you need). You can configure `ssh` itself to automatically accept a host key, or turn off host-key verification in the first place, and you should use public-key authentication, not passwords, for automated authentication.

Comment: @chepner I understand your advice but unfortunately, the work environment forces me to do this, there is no key-based authentication mechanism for the servers I'm working with, thank you.

Comment: "No key-base authentication mechanism". Does that mean they actually disabled key-based authentication (`PubkeyAuthentication=no` in the server config, e.g.), or that you just don't have a key *yet*? (If the latter, you can generate your own key and upload the public key yourself.)

Comment: @chepner No, they disabled key-based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <(cat << 'EOF'
spawn ssh MYHOST@MYSERVER
expect {
    -re "(authenticity of host|fingerprint)" { send -- "yes\r" }
}
expect {
    "password:" { send -- "secret\r" }
}
interact
EOF
)
```

If you want a one-liner :

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh MYHOST@MYSERVER; expect -re "(authenticity of host|fingerprint)" { send -- "yes\r" }; expect ".*password: " { send -- "secret\r" }; interact'
```

The first version uses process substitution because `expect` can take a file as argument, which is more readable.

Comment: Thank you, how can I make this inline and run it in the terminal? also, the third line where "process substitution happens" makes me confused, I searched for what it means and couldn't understand it, can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `expect` to recognize the fingerprint. You are being prompted to accept a fingerprint because the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option has its default value of `ask`. You can simply set it to `off` or `no` to automatically accept the key without prompting:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=off MYHOST@MYSERVER
```